# Cannot separate the distinct ids in MySQL query

Tags: sql, distinct, summary

> Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each vendor in the Invoices table that contains these columns:
>   The vendor_id column from the Vendors table
>   The sum of the invoice_total columns in the Invoices table for that vendor

```
SELECT 
    distinct vendor_id, SUM(invoice_total) AS Invoice_totals
FROM
    invoices i
    join vendors v using (vendor_id);
```

I am able to show all 34 vendor_ids without the SUM(invoice_total), but once I add that, it combines them all into one.  How can I avoid this happening?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Add a `Group By Vendor_ID` and remove the `Distinct`.

Comment: MySQL.  And thank you, that was the issue :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `select distinct` with `sum()`.  Use `group by`.  That makes the intent of the query much clearer.

Second, you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT vendor_id, SUM(i.invoice_total) AS Invoice_totals
FROM vendors v LEFT JOIN
     invoices i
     using (vendor_id)
GROUP BY vendor_id;
```

Comment: Ah. Putting `Vendors` first then doing a `LEFT JOIN` on the `Invoices` will show you `Vendors` with no `Invoices`. Good point.